# Is it okay to pass `this` in the render() method

Tags: reactjs

## TL;DR

Is this okay?

```
class SideMenu extends React.Component {

  render() {
    // note passing this
    return 
        <MenuGroup menu={this}/>
  }
}

class MenuGroup extends React.Component {

  handleClick() {
    this.props.menu.setState({ some: "thing" })
  }

  render() {
   ...
  }
}
```

## Background

I am trying to build a side-menu (like the one in sb-admin) using ReactJS.  (I know I could use react-metismenu, but I am doing this to learn how to use ReactJS)

There were two approaches I can think of to do this, but the [Context docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) kind of warned me enough to not use it for now especially since the **experimental API** part.

Anyway I had a bunch of components built but no real hierarchy at the moment (since it wasn't needed if I wasn't doing context).  But I needed to pass the object that would store the current state of the menu and allow me to update it.

What I am wondering is if what I did was okay or could it be better or should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

If your components get too complicated I recommend using some state management tool like `mobx` or `redux`. It is not a good idea to pass `this` down to the child components violates the react `one-way flow` principle.

You may be looking for this:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

In brief your code should look something like this:

```
class SideMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleMenuChange = this.handleMenuChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleMenuChange(value) { this.setState({something: value })

  render() {
    // note passing this
    return 
        <MenuGroup handleMenuChange={this.handleMenuChange}/>
  }
}

class MenuGroup extends React.Component {

  handleClick() {
    this.props.handleMenuChange("thing")
  }

  render() {
   ...
  }
}
```

This structure will allow you for easier reasoning and refactoring, moreover your child components are now reusable.